# MAthematical notation for sorting submatrix and replacing it back

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I need help in expressing the following paragraph in mathematical form as much as possible.

I have a matrix $A$ which is $N\times M$. 
For each element of $A$, $A(i,j)$, I consider a submatrix of $A$ and denotes it with $A'(i,j)$, $A'$ is a submatrix of $A$ with center at $(i,j)$ and with the size such as N2xN2 and N3xN3.

Then for each $A'$, I would like to apply function f(.) on A' (which is in two different sizes), let's say F1=f(A') for size N2xN2 and F2=f(A') for size N3x3.

Then I want to convert F1 and F2 to a vector and sort that vector and this sorted vector (which has the size of 1x(N2^2*N3^2) ) will be the elements of a new matrix (lets say B).

So matrix B has 3 dimension, the first 2 are the same as i and j and the third one is going to be the sorted vector which is created from sorted version of F1 and F2 together.

This is a loop that will happen for all $i$ and $j$ when $1<i<N$ and $1<j<M$.

I really appreciate it if anyone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think words would work better to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorting vector entries is not a mathematically useful operation, so we don't have any standard conventions for it. You'll have to create your own notation. What possible reason do you have for describing this mathematically?

Comment: @PaulSinclair How about a submatrix? is there any way for that?
I need it for my report.

Comment: To me, it seems like it would be much better to write this in pseudocode rather than trying to find a mathematical notation. Pseudocode is better suited for describing procedures.

Comment: @user326210 would you please tell me how to do it? I have never write anything in Pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your function is supposed to do or why you want this particular function, but here is approximately what pseudocode could look like:

```
 subroutine subMatrix(M, i, j, size) :
     N = matrix(size, size) // a new size x size matrix.
     for x = i; x < i+size; i = i+1 :
         for y = j; y < j+size; j=j+1 :
             N[x,y] = M[i,j]
     return N

 algorithm sortedOperation(M, matrix_fn, size1, size2) :`
     // M: a matrix
     // matrix_fn : a function that operates on a
                    matrix of any size, yielding 
                    another matrix of the same size.
     // size1, size2 : two positive integers

     m = width(M)
     n = height(M)

     R = matrix(m, n, m*m + n*n)

     for each row i in M
         for each column j in M:
             N1 = subMatrix(M, i, j, size1)
             N2 = subMatrix(M, i, j, size2)

             N1 = matrix_fn(N1)
             N2 = matrix_fn(N2)

             L = []
             for each entry in N1 : 
                 append the entry to L
             for each entry in N2 :
                 append the entry to L

             L = sort(L)
             for k = 0; k < len(L); k+ = 1 :
                 R[i,j,k] = L[k]
     return R
```